# How to UNNEST and flatten all the records in BigQuery when looking at Google Analytics

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery, unnest

When analyzing GA data in BigQuery, I found duplicate records with the same values for the following fields

- fullVisitorId
- visitStartTime
- hits.hitNumber

I filtered down the results a bit by a specific fullVisitorId and visitStartTime

```
SELECT
  fullVisitorId,
  visitStartTime,
  hits.hitNumber,
  hits.time,
  TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(CAST(visitStartTime + 0.001 * hits.time AS INT64)) AS hitsTimestamp
FROM
  `testGAview.ga_sessions_20200113`,
  UNNEST(hits) AS hits
WHERE
  fullVisitorId = '324982394082304'
  AND visitStartTime = 324234233
ORDER BY
  fullVisitorId,
  visitStartTime,
  hitNumber
```

The above query returns 13 records that have duplicate fullVisitorId, visitStartTime, and hits.hitNumber.  I'm not sure how this is possible because looking at the [schema][1], all of these fields being the same for a different row is unexpected. I should say that this is an extremely small % of records .002%, so I'm thinking it could be a processing issue on the GA end.

What I'd like to do now is unnest ALL of the fields to see the other values, alongside the fullVisitorId, visitStartTime, and hitNumber

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `testGAview.ga_sessions_20200113` UNNEST(hits) AS h,
WHERE
  fullVisitorId = '324982394082304'
  AND visitStartTime = 324234233
  AND hits.hitNumber = 23
```

What I'm hoping the above returns is 2 rows that meet the above conditions, and also shows values for all the other fields, to see if they are the exact same.

Can anybody help with this? Thanks!

Comment: And why doesn't your query do what you want?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit. I am getting this error: 'Duplicate column names in the result are not supported. Found duplicate(s): customDimensions'

Answer (score 0):

The real question seems to be "how to compare if two rows are identical". Am I right?

This would solve that problem:

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION first_two_identical(x ANY TYPE) AS (
   TO_JSON_STRING(x[OFFSET(0)]) = TO_JSON_STRING(x[OFFSET(1)])
);

SELECT first_two_identical(ARRAY_AGG(a)) identical
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801` a
WHERE visitId IN (1501583974, 1501616585)
```

- The SELECT chooses 2 rows (the full row), and packs them together in an array.
- The array is sent to the function `first_two_identical()`
- The function takes the first 2 elements of the arrray it receives.
- To transform the full rows into comparable objects, we used `TO_JSON_STRING()`.

That's it.